# how to remove white-space of hidden images for a category filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just did a category filter thing which consist to hide the images that I don't need, so if I click on the car logo at the top I will need to hide every element that doesn't contain "car" id, but the problem is that for some reason it keeps the hidden images dimensions.

for example:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

css code:

```
.block_container{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 632px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.5); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
.game_item{
    margin: 13px;
    width: 176px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hide{
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category_item').click(function(){
        var category=$(this).attr('id');

        if(category=='all'){
            $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.game_item').removeClass('hide');
            }, 300);
        } else{
            $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.'+category).removeClass('hide');
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you can do without the transition, you should just be able to set display:none. If you need the transition, you should try placing your images inside individual divs, and then doing your transition on the div

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please avoid posting pictures of the issue and instead descripe it. The question should be understandable even when the url of the image has vanished. The best way to show the issue is with a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (maybe with some "fake" images from https://picsum.photos/). At least the html part should be added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot the margin. When you set it to 0 for the class "*.hide*" it should work as desired.

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category_item').click(function(){
      var category=$(this).attr('id');

      if(category=='all'){
        $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.game_item').removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
      } else{
        $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.'+category).removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.block_container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 632px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.5); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

.game_item {
    margin: 13px;
    width: 176px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hide {
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="all" class="category_item" type="button">all</button>
    <button id="car" class="category_item" type="button">car</button>
    <button id="house" class="category_item" type="button">house</button>
    <button id="puzzle" class="category_item" type="button">puzzle</button>
</div>
<div class="block_container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/300" class="game_item puzzle" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300" class="game_item puzzle" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300" class="game_item house" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="game_item car" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" class="game_item car" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300" class="game_item house" />
</div>
```

---

By the way, i think that manipulating width, height, transform, etc. could be to much and it would be enough to just set `opacity: 0;` and `display: none;` (with jQuery `hide()`)

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category_item').click(function(){
      var category=$(this).attr('id');

      if(category=='all'){
        $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.game_item').show().removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
      } else{
        $('.game_item').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.game_item').hide();
          $('.'+category).show().removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.block_container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 632px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.5); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

.game_item {
    margin: 13px;
    width: 176px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button id="all" class="category_item" type="button">all</button>
    <button id="car" class="category_item" type="button">car</button>
    <button id="house" class="category_item" type="button">house</button>
    <button id="puzzle" class="category_item" type="button">puzzle</button>
</div>
<div class="block_container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/300" class="game_item puzzle" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300" class="game_item puzzle" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300" class="game_item house" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="game_item car" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" class="game_item car" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300" class="game_item house" />
</div>
```